# Using System Path Variable in Maven project - Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, tomcat

- **PROBLEM:** Hello everyone! I have created a Maven project in which i am building
  a `RESTful API`, now i have created few `.json` files in which i want
  to store my `JSON` data in `src/main/resources` , but as i can see
  every time i make a change ( example: register a user - write in a
  file ) all changes get lost whenever i redeploy the WAR file or the
  server gets restarted/reloaded.
- Can someone please tell me how to use system `PATH variable` to fix
  my problem? I want to store files somewhere i will be able to update
  them without having to worry if server is being reloaded or not. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there maybe a way to store them in tomcat folder or something?

Comment: Are you using the class loader to access your JSON files?

Comment: Yes i am using class loader. I am guessing thats not the right way to go.

Comment: You guessed right. Just nominate a directory in your file system, make sure it has the right permissions, and use that for storing your data file. Alternatively, consider using a database

Comment: Okay, if i am correct you are telling me to set the absolute path, but this is a university project, when i bring the code there i will have to change absolute path on each file, right? is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMART WAY, with java configuration and classpath (unix example, launch your application this way)

```
java -classpath $PATH <your-class-name>
```

or

```
setenv CLASSPATH = $PATH
```

see [unix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) and [windows instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

BAD WAY, within application code

1. You can read the PATH variable from the OS environment calling [System.getenv()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--) and then looking for the "PATH" elements within the returned map.
2. Then you have to parse the string (e.g. with [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)) obtained to get each folder within the PATH variable
3. you have to look for your JSON files in each of the folder from previous point

Comment: About the SMART WAY, do you mean to go to `Control-Panel -> System -> Advance Settings -> Enviroment Variables -> Path`  and append a path of the folder location in which i stored my .JSON files? If thats so how does that benifit me? On reloading servlet context (Redeploying WAR) the changes i made wont be deleted?

Comment: what you ask now is to do

    java -classpath <location-in-which-you-stored-your-.JSON-files> <your-class-name
but what you wrote in the original question is how to use "system PATH variable" and:

  1 I intended you meant you are going to put your .JSON files in a directory included in the PATH variable

  2 I showed you how to pass that PATH variable value to the java process so that your .JSON files will be seen from JAVA

Comment: 3 WAR redeploying is not an issue as long as you use the same command line every time.  The classpath will be set the same way every time

  4 you are supposing system PATH variable is a Microsoft Windows concept, but this is not right, a Linux shell has an equivalent PATH variable with the same meaning